# How can I monitor CPU Temperature in windows over SNMP?

Tags: windows, snmp

On linux you can use lm_sensors to expose CPU temperature to snmp, and use your tool of choice to graph it.  I'd like to do the same with Windows.

I found [SNMP-Informant](http://www.wtcs.org/informant/products.htm#Free%20Agents0) which offers two free agents that plug into Windows SNMP service.  I'm using the standard one to export Disk, Network, CPU, and Memory info to a linux box running Cacti.  It's perfect.

And their Motherboard Monitor is exactly what I'm looking for (exporting temperature, fan speeds, voltages) - except it requires 6-year-old MBM5 that doesn't even run, let alone list my new Gigabyte board in the motherboards to pick.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is with SpeedFan : http://deve.loping.net/projects/sfsnmp/

Comment: Alas, it seems this project is broken at the moment.  There's a recent thread on the forum about fixing it though, so hopefully it gets resolved soon.

Comment: It's still down. Any other suggestions???

Comment: Note that the version 0.1.2 available through the [project's download page](http://deve.loping.net/projects/sfsnmp/downloads/) and dating Nov 2010 claims to have Vista/7 compatibility on board.